# Squid logs retention

Tags: 12.04, log, squid

I have Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS installed. Squid keeps only last 3 days logs. Does anybody know how to increase this duration?

I use `cron` to rotate them on daily basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logrotate configuration file `/etc/logrotate.d/squid3` is already part of the squid3 package.

Edit this file to your needs.

E.g. set `rotate 7` to preserve 7 rotated versions of the log file.

See also: [man 8 logrotate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/logrotate.8.html)